# NSPredicate for finding only the first match

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsarray, nspredicate

In Core Data, I have a field called `UUID` which is a unique id.

Now, I want to fetch a single specific `UUID` record. For that i need to use `NSPredicate`. But from what I know, the predicate would search the entire data store. For example suppose  there are 10 records and I want to search for the `UUID` which has a value of `2`. The predicate will continue the search after it's found `2` (taking extra CPU cycles).

I want to know if we can optimise this. How can I make the predicate stop searching once its found the first object.

Comment: you can set `setFetchLimit` as 1 (limit you need) for you fetch request..

Comment: Thanks RAJA. Suppose i want to do same for NSArray.

Comment: refer Aggregate Operations in reference doc -  `array[FIRST] - Specifies the first element in the array array. ` link - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html

Comment: Raja That First is for multi demission array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Core Data, use `setFetchLimit:` on the fetch request to limit the number of results. You can also add an index to the UUID attribute if you are going to be using it frequently.

If you want to run the predicate on an array instead and limit the hits you would need to iterate the array yourself (`enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:`) and explicitly apply the predicate to each item (`evaluateWithObject:`). Then, when you find a match, use the `BOOL *stop` parameter of the block to end the iteration.